# validating uniqueness of many to many model by foreign key model field

Tags: python, django

I have 3 model:

```
class Citizenship(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class RestrictionGroup(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    citizenship = models.ManyToManyField(Citizenship)
```

I want my citizenship be unique based on related destination. If my destination is England, and if I have 5 restriction groups, each restriction groups related to destination have to unique citizenship.

for example,
[image]

at this image Greece is duplicated, but I need unique countries for destination country.

so how can validate this and return back friendly error message?

any help appreciated, thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with save_formset method and share my code if in the future anyone need it.

First I collect all citizenship values belongs to destination, after that I use set() method and compare len(list_data) with len(set_data) if not match that's mean duplicated value entered.

```
   def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
   instances = formset.save(commit=False)

   citizenship_list = []
   for dep in formset.cleaned_data:
       if dep.get('citizenship'):
           for country in dep.get('citizenship'):
               citizenship_list.append(country.name)

   citizenship_set = set(citizenship_list)
   if len(citizenship_list) != len(citizenship_set):
       self.message_user(request, message="Duplicate Citizenship value", level=messages.ERROR)
   else:
       for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
           obj.delete()
       for instance in instances:
           instance.user = request.user
           instance.save()
       formset.save_m2m()
```